# start avd error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, command-line, sdk

I am trying to learn to use my command line tools on mac but I am running into an error how do I fix this?

When I start the android virtual device below I am getting a panic

```
walker$ emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_P
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

When I enter either of the below commands I get the following error

```
walker$ avdmanager

walker$ sdkmanager
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema   at
>   com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>     at
>   com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>     at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
>     at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 5 more

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

This error usually means you are using an unsuitable `java` version.
In my case, the problem is solved when I downgraded `jdk12` to `jdk1.8`.

Comment: You can also keep using recent version of Java by using the latest command line tools -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71901000/310832